# Android feed.addItem() doesn't add last item

Tags: android, vector, jsoup, feedparser, nodelist

I don't understand why my code doesn't add all the 10 items to my feed, but just 9!

The cycle explores all the 10 items, but doesn't add the last one, I checked with Log.e.

Here's the code:

```
public class Parser {

    private Feed feed = new Feed();
    private ArrayList<String> categorie = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Feed parseXml(String xml) {
        int y = 1;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Tentativo di connessione */
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            /* Parse della pagina */
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            /* Prendi tutti i nodi "item" della pagina */
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                Item item = new Item();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                /* Prendi gli elementi necessari per ogni item */
                for (int j = 1; j < clength; j = j + 2) {

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;
                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                    /* Setta il titolo */
                    if (theString != null) {
                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setTitolo(theString);
                        }

                        /* Setta l'immagine */
                        else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {                          
                            // Prendi il link all'immagine 
                            String html = theString;
                            org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup.parse(html);
                            Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                            item.setImmagine(imgEle.attr("src"));
                        }

                        /* Setta il testo */
                        else if ("content:encoded".equals(nodeName)) {                      
                            theString = pulisciTesto(theString);
                            int start = theString.indexOf("L'articolo " + item.getTitolo());
                            String theString2 = theString.substring(start);
                            theString = theString.replaceAll(theString2, "");
                            item.setTesto(theString);
                        }

                        /* Setta la data */
                        else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                            /* Pulisci la data */
                            String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000","");
                            item.setData(formatedDate);
                        }

                        /* Setta l'autore */
                        else if ("dc:creator".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setAutore(theString);
                        }

                        /* Setta la categoria */
                        else if ("category".equals(nodeName)) {
                            if (checkCategoria(theString) != null)
                                item.setCategoria(checkCategoria(theString));
                        }

                        /* Setto il link all'articolo */
                        else if ("link".equals(nodeName)) {
                            item.setLink(theString);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.e("Notizia", item.getTitolo());
                y++;

                /* Aggiungi l'item alla lista degli item */
                feed.addItem(item);
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e("RuntimeException: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
    } 



        /* Ritorna il feed popolato */
        return feed;
    }       
}
```

Thanks for help!

EDIT: I changed the catch, now I get

```
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1528; index=-1
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:584)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1449)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at com.example.immoderati.parse.Parser.parseXml(Parser.java:85)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at com.example.immoderati.HomeActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:114)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at com.example.immoderati.HomeActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-20 19:42:48.653: E/RuntimeException:(6414):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: becuase such code: `catch (Exception e) { /*yum, tasty exception, i will eat it and do not share with anyone, not even log it nor print on screen*/ }` you will never know why ...

Comment: hi, I changed to  

catch (RuntimeException e) {
         Log.e("RuntimeException: ", e.getMessage());
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
     }

and i get 

02-20 19:16:12.873: E/RuntimeException:(31816): length=1528; index=-1

Comment: Use e.printstacktrace() and add log to the question

Comment: solved it, there was an error in the method that cleaned the text. Found it thanks to printstacktrace, thanks @Selvin

Comment: If its solved you can put the solution in the answer box provided and then accept it. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an error in the method that cleaned the text. Found it thanks to printstacktrace, thanks @Selvin